# Vmime Extract body of Email

Tags: email, vmime

How to extract the text content part of an email using the VMIME lib? I use the following code:

```
vmime::ref <vmime::body> body = Msg -> getBody();
vmime::ref <const vmime::contentHandler> cts = body -> getContents();
cts -> extract(out);
```

However, the content printed out is the whole body part of MIME structure of the email, including boundary and parameter settings.

```
--001a11c2e29cfe6d9f04e8b9a834
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

test1

--001a11c2e29cfe6d9f04e8b9a834
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<div dir="ltr"><br clear="all"><div>test1</div>
</div>

--001a11c2e29cfe6d9f04e8b9a834--
```

What I need is just the text content. However, I cannot find any API to extract just the text content.

What I need:

```
test1
```

I have been stuck for 3 days. Could anyone help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use vmime::messageParser object to parse your message. This way, you will get the text contents via the vmime::textPart objects (use getTextPartList() method on messageParser).

Vincent

Comment: Yeah~! I also tried messageParser. However, when I use:    mp.getTextPartAt(i) -> getText() -> extract(out);   This print nothing on the console. Could you tell me what is wrong